# Function for add item in cart with SKU

Tags: javascript, cart

I have zero block with custom buttom for add item to cart, i can add href attribute for send item name, price and image url for cart

```
#order: Item name= 399:::image=https://xxx_.jpg
```

If i use default button from tilda, when i click on button it send to cart: item name, price, image urla and SKU (vendor code) from catalouge which the will send when form submited ...

Maybe i can use core javascript function from tilda to add item to cart with all parametrs (name, price, image, SKU)?

Answer (score 0):

I researched the tilde page and found the answer

`javascript:tcart__addProduct({name: 'xxxx', price: 200, sku: 'hsh', img: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/xxxxx/photo.jpg'})`

[image]